# Maximum value of the loot, Knapsack problem

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, knapsack-problem

**Problem Introduction**
A thief finds much more loot than his bag can fit. Help him to find the most valuable combination of items assuming that any fraction of a loot item can be put into his bag.

Problem Description
Task. The goal of this code problem is to implement an algorithm for the fractional knapsack problem.

Input Format. The first line of the input contains the number  of items and the capacity  of a knapsack. The next  lines define the values and weights of the items. The -th line contains integers  and —the value and the weight of -th item, respectively.

Constraints. 1 ≤  ≤ 10^3, 0 ≤  ≤ 2 · 10^6; 0 ≤  ≤ 2 · 10^6, 0 <  ≤ 2 · 10^6 for all 1 ≤  ≤ . All the numbers are integers.

**MY CODE**:

```
import sys
import unittest

def get_optimal_value( tot_capacity, weights_kg, values_money):
    amount = 0.
    value_per_item = [float(v) / float(w) for v, w in zip(values_money, weights_kg)]
    value_per_item.sort(reverse = True)
    print(value_per_item)
    for i in range(len(values_money)):
        if tot_capacity == 0:
            return amount
            break
        add_capacity = min(tot_capacity, weights_kg[i])
        amount = amount + add_capacity * value_per_item
        weights_kg[i] = weights_kg[i] - add_capacity
        tot_capacity = tot_capacity - add_capacity
    return amount

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = list(map(int, sys.stdin.read().split()))
    item, tot_capacity = data[0:2]
    values_money = data[2:(2 * item + 2):2]
    weights_kg = data[3:(2 * item + 2):2]
    opt_value = get_optimal_value(tot_capacity, weights_kg, values_money)
    print("{:.10f}".format(opt_value))
```

I am getting **"Process finished with exit code -1"** as an error. please help me in correcting this code

Comment: "assuming that any fraction of a loot item can be put into his bag" if you can put any part of an item in, this is not a knapsack problem but instead rather trivial.

Comment: I edit the the constraint part, its 10^3, 10^6. Sorry for the error.